# Remove parent slugs from URLs on three customs posts types

Tags: custom-post-types

Good evening everyone.

I have three Custom Post Types and i want to remove the parent slugs from them.

```
$args = array(
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/','with_front' => true),
);
```

`functions.php`

```
function wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
              if ( 'CPT1' != $post->post_type )
             return $post_link;

               $uri = '';
               foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
                  $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
                }

              return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
            }
            add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

In this point i wonder how can use the function wpse_101072_flatten_hierarchies and add inside the cases of the other 2 CPT.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add more conditions to the [`if( 'CPT1' != $post->post_type )` construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). Separate and describe the relationship between condition [expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) using [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
function wpse_222797a_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
  // IF( 'CPT1' IS NOT the post_type
  //     AND 'CPT2' IS NOT the post_type 
  //     AND 'CPT3' IS NOT the post_type )                  
  // THEN exit the function and RETURN the unmodified link.
  if( 'CPT1' != $post->post_type
      && 'CPT2' != $post->post_type
      && 'CPT3' != $post->post_type )
    return $post_link;

  // If execution reaches this point, the post_type must be 'CPT1', 'CPT2',
  // or 'CPT3', so produce and return a modified link.
  // [...]
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_222797a_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

Alternately, check the current post type against an array of post-types requiring link modification by leveraging [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
function wpse_222797b_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
  $modified_post_types = [ 'CPT1', 'CPT2', 'CPT3' ];

  // IF the post_type IS NOT in the $modified_post_types array
  // THEN exit the function and return the unmodified link
  if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, $modified_post_types ) )
    return $post_link;

  // If execution reaches this point, the post_type must be one of the ones
  // in the $modified_post_types array, so produce and return a modified link.
  // [...]
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_222797b_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I will see and i will write my comments again.

Comment: My code is conflict and i don't know why this happened. When i make the changes it cannot be possible to remove the 'slugs' from these 3 CPT, but only 1, more specific the last. Some important feedback : 1) My CPT need to be hierarchical ?Until now is "true". 2) The syntax of `"'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/','with_front' => true),"` is correct?

Comment: @MikeD Sorry, missed that in your original post. No, `'slug'` should be how you wish your post-type to be represented in the URL, i.e. `'cpt1'`. See [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite).

Comment: i read this : " 'slug' => string Customize the permalink structure slug. Defaults to the $post_type value. Should be translatable. " . My settings : `'rewrite'  => array('slug' => 'CPT-1', 'with_front' => true),` also i change the permalinks to "Day and time" as an example or "post name" but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :  I try to rename the parent  / URL rewrite rule from CPT's
$args array from CPT1 *I follow the same way for CPT2 and CPT3*
So in the begging i wanted to create from this : 
`mydomain.com/CPT_1/CPT_1` to this :  `mydomain.com/CPT_1`

but now i have thoughts to create this:

`mydomain.com/about-us/CPT_1`

```
$args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'CPT 1', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'post-formats', ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'can_export'            => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'my-slug' ),
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'CPT_1', $args );
```

in `functions.php`

```
function name1_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'CPT_1' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    $uri = '';
    foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
        $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
    }
    return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'name1_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

the 2nd flatten

```
function name2_flatten_hierarchies( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'CPT_2' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    $uri = '';
    foreach ( $post->ancestors as $parent ) {
        $uri = get_post( $parent )->post_name . "/" . $uri;
    }
    return str_replace( $uri, '', $post_link );
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'name2_flatten_hierarchies', 10, 2 );
```

My rewrite rule :

```
function my_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule( 
            '^CPT_1/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?post_type=CPT_1&name=$matches[1]',
            'top',

            '^CPT_2/([^/]+)/?$',
            'index.php?post_type=CPT_2&name=$matches[1]',
            'top'

        );
        add_permastruct( 'about-us', '/about-us/%about-us%/' );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_rule', 10 );
```

But in this case the rewrite rules are working, for CPT_2 show me the CPT but for CPT_1 not show me and redirect me in the `index.php` *(CPT_1 is the first CPT that i add)*.